# Desktop notifications sent by i3blocks don't show up if some window in full-screen mode

Tags: i3, notify-send

I am using `i3 window manager` on Ubuntu with `i3blocks` to display some important info in `i3bar`. I need a desktop notification when something requires my attention (for example, battery level) as well. To reach this I use the `notify-send --urgency=critical` command in the `command` property of the corresponding blocklet in `i3blocks`' config:

```
[test]
full_text=Test
command=notify-send --urgency=critical "Test" "Test"
interval=2
```

It works as intended *unless some window in full-screen mode*. If so, notifications just stop appearing until exiting full-screen.

I am not 100% sure it is about `i3blocks` --- only 99%. Why?
Because everything works as intended if executed from terminal. For example, try this shell script:

```
sleep 5;
notify-send --urgency=critical "Test" "Test";
sleep 2;
notify-send --urgency=critical "Test" "Test";
```

after executing it just change focused window and turn it in full-screen --- you'll see two notifications.

---

This is some additional info:

*Linux* : Ubuntu 16.04

*Window manager* : i3

*Notification daemon* : dunst

---

I could provide my dot files (dunst, i3blocks, i3, etc) but as I said if I throw notifications from a shell script everything's fine.

## UPDATE

It seems that `i3blocks` stop updating blocks in full-screen at all!
I've tested it by the following blocklet:

```
[test]
full_text=Test
command=echo "Test" >> ~/Temp/test
interval=2
```

and after turning a terminal in full-screen this file stop being updated.

---

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that relies on [`i3` IPC protocol](https://i3wm.org/docs/ipc.html). It allows a user to interact with `i3` from the outside world. For example, a user can subscribe to an `i3` event ("window changed its fullscreen mode" in our case) and connect a callback to this event (send the `SIGCONT` to `i3blocks`).

There are several libraries written for different PLs (see 5th section in i3 IPC documentation) which provide user interface to that protocol. I chose the [`Python` one](https://github.com/altdesktop/i3ipc-python). Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess, os, signal
from i3ipc import Event, Connection

def on_fullscreen( i3, e ) :
    """
    A callback which is called every time a window
    changes its fullscreen mode
    """
    try :
        process = subprocess.Popen( ['pgrep', 'i3blocks'],
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    universal_newlines=True )
        pid = int( process.stdout.readline().split()[0] )
        os.kill( pid, signal.SIGCONT ) 
    except :
        i3.main_quit()

i3 = Connection()

i3.on( Event.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_MODE, on_fullscreen )

i3.main()
```

I put this code into python script named `i3blocks_awake.py`. Now all we need to do is to execute this script everytime `i3` starts up. So from the `i3` [documentation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_automatically_starting_applications_on_i3_startup) we know that `exec_always` is what we need. So I put the following line in my `i3` config file (at the very end):

```
exec_always --no-startup-id '/home/lrdprdx/.config/i3/i3block_awake.py'
```

Restart `i3` and voila, all my notifications work as intended.

---

I think this is not 100% safe and clever solution but it works. For example, every time `i3` restarts the connection with the socket is lost so script restarts too. If you see some flaws here, please, say.